# Ubuntu 18.04.1 - suspend - how's it supposed to operate?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, laptop

I have recently upgraded from 16.04 LTS and miss the option to suspend when pressing the power icon in the top bar, as no such option is available in 18.04.

One [recent site](https://www.linuxnov.com/3-methods-to-suspend-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver/) suggests holding the power button down till a suspend option appears - it doesn't - it just powers off. I have set the settings option to suspend on pressing power button and indeed it does if pressed briefly but a long press turns the machine off.

Typing 'suspend' in the new Show Applications does bring up a button which does work but this is a round-the-houses way of doing things. It looks like shutting the lid on my laptop does suspend the machine. I leave my laptop with the lid down after I've turned it off, so I would like a quick way of doing it with the lid open and without hitting the power button.

**Edit:**
Model is an Asus X555L

uname -r
4.15.0-32-generic

Answer (score 3):

You don't hold the power button until the suspend option appears.

You push the power button once and the window panel menu appears.

Then you click and hold the power icon on the window panel.

Optionally you can hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key when hitting the power icon (the down arrow) in the top bar, not the physical button.

Comment: No, it does not operate like this. If I briefly touch the physical power button when settings are set to power off, a menu with options 'cancel' 'restart' and 'power off' shows. There is no option for 'suspend'.

Comment: I'll investigate this further over the weekend. Can you update your question with your laptop make and model please? Also output of `uname -r`. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/how-to-access-suspend-button-in-ubuntu.html explains it better. The 'Alt' method works when hitting the power icon (the down arrow) in the top bar, not the physical button.

Comment: @NickT Much appreciated. I've updated the answer with your comment.