# How do I put Ubuntu 18.04 on standby? Suspend Ubuntu?

Tags: suspend, standby

How do I put Ubuntu 18.04 on standby? The option appears to be gone.

(I specifically want to be able to do it though the GUI, without pressing the physical button on my computer.)

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: What do you mean by "standby"? Suspend or hibernation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04.1 - suspend - how's it supposed to operate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066208/ubuntu-18-04-1-suspend-hows-it-supposed-to-operate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Act as if you were going to shut down the computer, but click and hold the power off symbol, it will change to a pause symbol.

[image: putubuntuonstandby]

Answer (score 0):

Create a polkitd rule

```
cat /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla 
# aktiviere hibernate
[Re-enable hibernation]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Comment: This will enable hibernation.

Comment: Great, I always be confused about that.